# google maps v2 Rendering Issue

Tags: android

I am working with Android Volley & using a self certificated SSL.
I have implemented the Google maps but the issue is that it shows only the Visible area of screen. I move map from left to right[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4YOx.png) it gives a blurry maps and not rendered completely.

1. [Map Load Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvXT1.png)
2. [Map Not Loaded correct when swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4YOx.png)

When I not Call Https only call Http volley it works perfectly.

**Code :
SSL Socket factory**
 public static SSLSocketFactory sGetSocketFactory(Activity activity) {

```
    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {

        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
        Certificate ca;
        try {

            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.e("CERT", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }


        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);


        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                Log.e("CipherUsed", session.getCipherSuite());
                return hostname.compareTo("192.168.1.1")==0;

                      //  ; //The Hostname of your server.

            }
        };


        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        SSLContext context = null;
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
        return sf;

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return  null;
}
```

Comment: Daiko bhai aesay ni hota....certificate aesay ni mil jatay......